# Локализация данных из iCloud

Tags: ios, swift

Здравствуйте. Разработал приложения под iOS, работающее с бд iCloud. Сразу возникли два вопроса:

1. Интерфейс программы локализовать не проблема, а вот данные, получаемые из бд iCloud, я не знаю как локализовать. Возможно ли каким-то образом определение языка в смартфоне, чтобы делать проверку в приложении? Или я, возможно, не в том направлении размышляю, может есть более оптимальная идея локализации.
2. Поиск определенных записей в бд. При нажатии на определенную запись в приложении, хотелось бы загружать соответственную картинку из iCloud. Вот с этим вопросом у меня совсем нет идей.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение моих вопросов.

Comment: А каким образом происходит запрос к базе данных: в самом приложении формируется SQL и подключение к базе или все же идет запрос на какой-то API и возвращается ответ в виде JSON/XML?

Comment: На основе API. Стандартное обращение к бд iCloud, взятое из developer.apple. Хотел прислать пример из кода, не очень понятно получается, могу скрин только попробовать скинуть
http://cs623620.vk.me/v623620778/3d35f/bAx5G9GorzY.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Чтобы получить локаль в iOS:

   let language = NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations.first as NSString
2. Хранить URL картинки в iCloud в базе данных с привязкой к записям. При запросе записей этот URL уже будет известен, и при нажатии на запись просто формировать UIImage с данным URL.

Поделюсь идеей локализации в базе данных, которую недавно реализовал в одном из приложений, может подойдет.

Создаем таблицу следующей структуры (`locales`):

```
- `ID` - уникальный идентификатор записи
- `en` - строка на английском
- `ru` - строка на русском
- ...
- `de` - строка на немецком
```

В каждой таблице, в которой есть ячейка с текстом, подлежащая переводу, делаю *foreign_key* с ячейки на `ID` в `locales`. Дальше дело техники создать нужный запрос, который вытащит нужный текст. Если такой локали нет в базе, то используем какую нибудь локаль по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо большое, завтра попробую реализовать, обязательно отпишусь

Comment: Все прекрасно работает, еще раз спасибо за советы.